# How to insert password into email "template" file?

Tags: java, email

My web app sends "forgot password" and other emails. I'd like to have email body template somewhere in a file, so that each customer can change the way the "forgot password" email looks.

For example:

```
Dear App Name user,
Your new password is: %password%

Your App Name Team.
```

I understand that the message body can go into a file, but how do I replace %password% from my Java code?

Any other ideas how this should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
String template="Dear App Name user,\nYour new password is: %s \n\nYour App Name Team."

String email=String.format(template,password);
```

Basically, you can use `%s` as a placeholder which will be filled with the password by String.format

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [freemarker templates](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/freemaker-template-hello-world-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

You have various options:

- Use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)
- Use [`MessageFormat.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)
- Use a template engine like Velocity or FreeMarker